# Is there some geometric intuition for the quotient $G/Z(G)$, where $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, intuition, quotient-spaces

Let $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the $n$th general linear group. Its center $Z(G)$ is given by all scalar matrices $aI$ with nonzero determinant.
How can I get an intuitive picture of $G/Z(G)$? I know that the equivalence relation is obviously $A\sim B$ iff there exists $\lambda\neq 0$ such that $A=\lambda B$, but I'm having trouble getting a concrete picture.

Comment: It is actually precisely isomorphic to the *special linear group* $SL_n(\Bbb R)$, group of all matrices with determinant $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: there are two issues with that: the determinant may not be positive, and $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ has scalar matrices too.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This isn't quite correct, $G / Z(G)$ is the *projective general linear group*.

Comment: @Travis gah! Rookie mistake

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't think I'd seen a mistake before among your (numerous and helpful) comments on this site, prompting me to check this to make sure I hadn't misremembered this myself. This situation is particularly deceptive in that the groups *do* agree for odd parity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, this is the [*projective linear group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group), sometimes denoted $PGL(n, \Bbb R)$. There are only finitely many elements in $SL(n, \Bbb R)\cap Z(G)$, so the homomorphism
$$SL(n, \Bbb R) \hookrightarrow GL(n, \Bbb R) \to PGL(n, \Bbb R)$$
is an immersion and (as Lie groups),
$$\dim PGL(n, \Bbb R) = \dim GL(n, \Bbb R) - \dim Z(GL(n, \Bbb R)) = n^2 - 1 = \dim SL(n, \Bbb R) .$$ (The image of $SL(n, \Bbb R)$ under this map is denoted $PSL(n, \Bbb R)$.)
Thus, $PGL(n, \Bbb R)$ locally looks like $SL(n, \Bbb R)$, that is, they have the same universal cover, which is usually denoted $\widetilde{SL(n, \Bbb R)}$.

Now, $\det (a I) = a^n$, so if $n$ is odd, the only scalar matrix in $SL(n, \Bbb R)$ is $I$, and it follows that $SL(n, \Bbb R) \cong PGL(n, \Bbb R)$.

On the other hand, if $n$ is even, then the scalar matrices in $SL(n, \Bbb R)$ are $\pm I$, so in this case $SL(n, \Bbb R) \to PSL(n, \Bbb R)$ is a $2$-fold cover, and it follows from some topology that $SL(n, \Bbb R) \not\cong PGL(n, \Bbb R)$.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean with "there are only finitely many elements in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$"? I am surely understanding the sentence wrong.

Comment: @marcotrevi There are only finite many elements common to the two sets.

Comment: I permitted myself to edit your answer.

Comment: @marcotrevi Cheers, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

One might get some if none intuition about a group by knowing where it acts. In this case this group acts naturally on projective space, and in fact transitively and faithfully.